# C# - Adding an element to an array causes IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to add an item to an array in C#. I can not take shortcuts such as using lists.

I understand that to do this I must create a new array. This is the code that I have already.

```
  public void addAtLocation(int location, String element)
  {
    String[] newMyArray = new string[myArray.Length + 1];

    for (int oldIndex = 0, newIndex = 0; oldIndex < myArray.Length + 1; oldIndex++, newIndex++)
    {

        if (newIndex == location)
        {
          newMyArray[oldIndex] = element;
          oldIndex--;
        }
        else
        {
          newMyArray[newIndex] = myArray[oldIndex];
        }
      }

    myArray = newMyArray;

  }
```

I'm not looking for just a fix my code solution. I need to understand why this is happening.

Comment: When you debug this, which line throws the exception and what are the runtime values when that happens?  Also, why on Earth can't you just use a `List<T>`?

Comment: Shouldn't the end criteria be `oldIndex < myArray.Length ` without the `+1`?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't take a "shortcut" and use a `List<string>`. No need to "reinvent the wheel".  Also a `List<T>` will typically be more efficient than resizing an array on every addition.

Comment: You need to store in a variable this code `myArray.Length + 1` before using it into for loop condition. If you not do it, it will reestimate every loop which can make subtle bug

Comment: also if you are really bent on using an `Array` first use List<string> then assign those values to an array by using extension method .ToArray() of that List
for example `var myList = new List<string>() var myArray = myList.ToArray()` I would personally stick to `List<T>`

Comment: `oldIndex < myArray.Length + 1` will inevitable reach an index 1 greater than the length of `myArray`.

Comment: @AndersForsgren If I  make your modification it no longer throws the exception, however it removes the last item from the array when adding an item to the desired index... i.e. 1 2 3 4 5, adding C to index 3 creates an array with 1 2 3 C 4 and drops the last element that was in the original array.

Comment: @iCantEven well, it works for me. I tried out with an array sized 5.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, the condition must be either `oldIndex <= myArray.Length - 1`
or `oldIndex < myArray.Length`, not `oldIndex < myArray.Length + 1`.

```
public void addAtLocation(int location, String element)
  {
    String[] newMyArray = new string[myArray.Length + 1];

    for (int oldIndex = 0, newIndex = 0; oldIndex <= myArray.Length - 1; oldIndex++, newIndex++)
    {

        if (newIndex == location)
        {
          newMyArray[oldIndex] = element;
          oldIndex--;
        }
        else
        {
          newMyArray[newIndex] = myArray[oldIndex];
        }
      }

    myArray = newMyArray;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your troubles stem from it being hard to read. Try a different approach.

```
public void addAtLocation(int location, String element)
  {
    String[] newMyArray = new string[myArray.Length + 1];
    int addedUnit = 0;//sort of like a flag to indicate the element has been inserted

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {

        if (i == location)
        {
          newMyArray[i] = element;
          newMyArray[i+1] = myArray[i]; //add two elements
          addedUnit = 1;
        }
        else
        {
          newMyArray[i+addedUnit] = myArray[i];
        }

      }

    myArray = newMyArray;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem is the conditional of the for loop. You are trying to decrease `oldIndex` inside the loop to keep track of which items have been copied but since it is your loop variable, you actually end up running past the end of the new array as `newIndex` gets incremented every time.

Change `newIndex` to be the loop variable in the condition:

```
for (int oldIndex = 0, newIndex = 0; newIndex < myArray.Length + 1; oldIndex++, newIndex++)
```

Note that this works better than changing the condition to be `oldIndex < myArray.Length` which would miss adding the new item at the last position.

Note that this is actually overly complicated even if you can't use `List<string>` because there are built-in methods for copying arrays. For example:

```
public void addAtLocation(int location, string element)
{
    string[] newMyArray = new string[myArray.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(myArray, 0, newMyArray, 0, location);
    newMyArray[location] = element;
    Array.Copy(myArray, location, newMyArray, location + 1, myArray.Length - location);
    myArray = newMyArray;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code:

```
for (int oldIndex = 0, newIndex = 0; oldIndex < myArray.Length + 1; oldIndex++, newIndex++)
```

is going to throw an index out of bounds exception.  Why? Well, just carefully walk through the code. Basically, you need to pretend that you are the Visual Studio debugger, and step through the code (trust me, we all do this). As you walk the code, I think you will quickly realize that this is what you really need to do:

```
for (int oldIndex = 0, newIndex = 0; oldIndex < myArray.Length; oldIndex++, newIndex++)
```

Reason being, your intention was to walk the **old** array (the one that's 1 less than the new one), and copy the values over to the new array. But the actual code was trying to walk the old array for the number of elements in the **new** array **plus** one...  Yeah - you had the opposite operator. Easy peasy!

Comment: It should be `<=` not `<`.

Comment: If you went through the myArray you have to go until < Length. Not < Length - 1. In the latter case the last element will never be reached.